# Azure database copy feature pricing

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

Currently our production azure SQL database is a P1.  We'd like to replicate or copy this database as our QA database.  Our QA database doesn't need to be anything more than a S1.  Does anyone know if the action of copying a database costs money?  If I wanted to run a azure function to copy the database every night to the same azure SQL server would it be costly?  I know in the azure function, after a successful copy, i have to lower it from a P1 to and S1.  The Azure documentation about copying a database doesn't talk about pricing.

Another question, Does anyone know if you can replicate a P1 azure SQL database to a S1?  That would be better than a azure function copy every night.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Does copying a database cost money?**

Assuming you mean use the "Copy" function inside the database blade or the "New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy" PowerShell command, I have done this several time's and it does not result additional costs. If you are copying via some sort of manual method via script, then it would simply utilize DTU's when the copy process is occurring.

**Copying the database every night**

Performing the copy every night using the built in copy functions would not cause additional costs, but this wouldn't be the best way to accomplish what you want. Instead of doing that, why not setup replication using a synch group (as you hinted at) which is easy to setup and even easier to maintain. See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54935622/azure-sql-database-sandbox-based-on-production/54953738#54953738) about how to do that.

**Copying/Synching between SQL Service Levels**

Lastly, unless the database exceeds the 1 TB S1 storage size limit, there is no reason why you can't synch a P1 to an S1 in a sync group.